# How do i load content from .php files with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im using AJAX and History.js to load content from separate pages into index-page. But for some reason i can only load .html-pages - how do i make this function load .php-pages?

Is the solution to add extensions in in var = urlPath? Other ideas?

```
// AJAX LOAD ONKLIK
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
    var title = $(this).text();

    History.pushState({urlPath: urlPath}, title, urlPath);
    $("#content").load(urlPath);      
    return false; 
});
```

**EDIT:**

I using links with no extension for example loading the page 'about.html':

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

which generates this url in browser when testing locally:

```
http://localhost/about
```

Thats all ok, but nothing happens when i try loading a .php-page fx 'home.php' the same way - nothing gets loaded. Seems like the AJAX / History.js breaks somehow.

BUT - if i add the extension .php in the link for page 'home.php', the page loads via AJAX just like .html-pages:

```
<a href="/home.php">About</a>
```

However this link will add the extension .php in the browser on local test:

```
http://localhost/home.php
```

So does anyone know if History.js only accepts .html files when working with AJAX, or am i missing something here?

Comment: What exactly is the value of `urlPath`? If it starts with `file://` then that's your problem.

Comment: Where do i locate the value of 'urlPath'?

Comment: Add `console.log(urlPath);` and look at the console (in web developer tools or firebug) or add `alert(urlPath)` inside the click handler.

Comment: alert(urlPath) shows the path in links as defined inside a href - fx /about - nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Your function auto load url from  attibute href in tag a

You must modify this line to php file

```
var urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
   var urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
   var title = $(this).text();

   History.pushState({urlPath: urlPath}, title, urlPath);
   //$("#content").load(urlPath);      
   $.ajax({
       url: urlPath,
       dataType: 'html',
       success : function(response){
              $("#content").html(response);
       }
   });
   return false; 
});
```

Comment: it will not do anything, run it on apache server?

Comment: Im using WAMP (Apache) for local testing. Even if i choose only '.php' in 'dataType' AJAX still loads .html, but not .php

Comment: run in firebug console

$.ajax({
       url: '/home.php',
       success : function(zwrotka){
              console.log(zwrotka);
       },
       error : function(zwrotka){
              console.log(zwrotka, 'error');
       }
   });

and show result from console

Answer (score 0):

**LAST EDIT / ANSWER:**

I found an answer to my question - actually the issue wasnt related to AJAX / History.js, but had to do with my local test-server.

In order to rewrite urls so link will work with no extension, add the following rules in an .htaccess og place it in root of server - now both .html and .php - pages will load if the link looks like this `<a href="/home">About</a>`

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php