# Ajax failed to load contents from php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to display contents of a php file on my html page using ajax.

I have an html file with the following ajax code :

**get_ajax.html**

```
<form action="">
 First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onblur="show users(this.value)">
 </form>

<p>Username: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 

 <script>
function showHint(str) {
var xhttp;
if (str.length == 0) { 
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;
}
 xhttp = newXMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
 }
 };
 xhttp.open("GET", "user.php?u="+str, true);
 xhttp.send();   
}
</script>
```

**user.php**

```
 <?php

echo $_GET["u"];?>
```

It doesn't display the username on my get_ajax.html page.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you tried ``console.log(xhttp.responseText)``,
and why you don't use something like jquery it is simple and straight forward

Comment: @Starkeen I would not use ajax

Comment: Go to this question it should help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180525/how-do-i-load-content-from-php-files-with-ajax

Comment: your code appears to be correct but has typo in the function name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check the existence of `user.php` and verify the proper path,by the way why  don't use Jquery,it is easy and straight forward.

Here is an example using jquery :

```
var str = 'something';

$.get('user.php',{u:str},function(serverResponse){

$("#txtHint").html(serverResponse); //this should add the value something to the DOM

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Appears you have type in your code as below

```
- onblur , you are making a call to "show users(this.value)" 
- there is a space between "show" and "user" , even u correct the space , you dont have a function "showuser" anywhere.
- your function to make the ajax call is "showHint"
- next you need a space between "new" and "XMLHTTpRequest()"

<form action="">
 First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onblur="showHint(this.value)"/>
 </form>
<p>Username: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</form>



<script>
function showHint(str) {
var xhttp;
if (str.length == 0) {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
return;
}
 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
 }
 };
 xhttp.open("GET", "user.php?u="+str, true);
 xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```